# How to enter input in this session?

Tags: kali-linux, mailman

[image]

I try to select the option but it doesn't work. Which key(s) do I use to enter it?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the language you're on, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the "Ok" button and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the button.